# React | How can i display my image in React?

Tags: reactjs

How can i display my image in react?

i know this is a basic question but im really having hard time just displaying my images. in some framework i can store it on asset folder but how can i do this in react js?

I call my images on App.js component
by calling this way.

```
import macbookPiso from './images/design/macbookPiso.png';

<div class="macbook">
   <img src={macbookPiso.png }/>
</div>
```

[image: Below is the structure of my app]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `require`

```
<div class="macbook">
   <img src={require("./images/design/macbookPiso.png") }/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put the image path in `src` attribute with `require` call

```
<img src={require('./images/design/macbookPiso.png')}/>
```

or using your way

```
var  macbookPiso  = require './images/design/macbookPiso.png';

<div class="macbook">
   <img src={macbookPiso }/>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it works just what i wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use create-react-app, you can also import the image and store in a variable.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png'; // Tell Webpack this JS file uses this image

function Header() {
  // Import result is the URL of your image
  return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}

export default Header;
```